# How do I load a non-latest Tensorflow checkpoint?

Tags: tensorflow

I made checkpoints every 1000 steps of training, and I have 16 files in my checkpoints directory. However it seems that when I want to retrieve the latest one it's reverting to its pre-trained state. I am assuming something to do with the summary logs not documenting that later checkpoints exist.

```
chkpt.restore(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(chkpt_dir))
# fit(train_ds, test_ds, steps=100000)

for i in range(10):
    ex_input, ex_output = next(iter(test_ds.take(1)))
    generate_images(generator, ex_input, ex_output, i, test=True)
```

How can I manually ask the checkpoint manager to retrieve this or that particular checkpoint file, as oppossed to `.latest_checkpoint()`?

Edit: Solved it myself, open the checkpoints.txt file in your checkpoint folder and set the suffix number to whichever checkpoint you want to load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the checkpoints.restore() method to restore checkpoints of your preference. For example, if you want to load checkpoint at iteration 1000, then you write:

```
checkpoint.restore('./test/model.ckpt-1000')
```

For more details please refer to this [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Checkpoint#restore). Thank You.